# How to organize interaction between web form and database in golang web app?

Tags: go

I'm creating small web app and I want to organize interaction between DB in main package and handlers which located in other package ("handlers"). And i want to find out can i set interaction between handlers in another package and db or it is bad practice to place handler not in the main package?

```
package main

import (
    "handlers"
    "net/http"
)

func main() {
    //...

    DB, err = ConnectToPostgres()
    //...
    http.HandleFunc("/adduser/", handlers.AddUser)
    http.HandleFunc("/getinfo/", handlers.GetUserInfo)
    http.ListenAndServe(":8080", nil)
}
```

Comment: You *can* have handlers anywhere you want, a package separate from main is ok. You can have the handlers package declare an exported, package level `DB` variable and then have the main package set that `handlers.DB` variable after initializing it.

Comment: Keep in mind that having a "global" db dependency is generally considered bad practice, at the least it will make testing your code more difficult.

Comment: Can I find out how then to do it to be a good practice?

Comment: Since it's a small web app I assume you're the only dev working on it, in that case you do you. i.e. It's good if it works for you, it's bad if it doesn't.

Comment: *"Can I find out how then to do it to be a good practice?"* the opposite of "global" is "local", i.e. you need to turn the global dependency into a local one, and a common approach to that is to use struct types with their fields holding the local dependencies and their methods used as the handlerfuncs.

Answer (score 1):

I always use this code

```
package providers

import (
    "fmt"
    "github.com/jinzhu/gorm"
    _ "github.com/jinzhu/gorm/dialects/postgres"
    "log"
)

var SQL *gorm.DB

type Postgres struct{}

func (s Postgres) Connect() *gorm.DB {
    dsn := s.getDSN()
    instance, err := gorm.Open("postgres", dsn)
    if err != nil {
        log.Panicf("Postgres Error: %+v", err)
    }
    return instance
}

func (s *Postgres) getDSN() string {
    c := Config.Storage.Postgres
    dsn := fmt.Sprintf("user=%s", c.User)
    if c.Pass != "" {
        dsn += fmt.Sprintf(" password=%s", c.Pass)
    }
    dsn += fmt.Sprintf(" host=%s", c.Host)
    dsn += fmt.Sprintf(" dbname=%s", c.Name)
    if !c.SSL {
        dsn += " sslmode=disable"
    }
    return dsn
}

func init() {
    conn := Postgres{}
    SQL = conn.Connect()
    SQL.LogMode(false)
    if Config.App.Debug {
        SQL.LogMode(true)
    }
}
```